# Third level HTMX back to original page?

Tags: django, htmx

I am using Django & HTMX.

I have two sites, lets say **site FOO** and **site BAR**

They both load ***HTMX page #1*** on load as part of the DOM- a list.

There are links on HTMX page #1 for a modal- ***HTMX page #2*** that provides details and CRUD for the items on the list.

I am trying to code DRY and need a way for a submit button on a modal *HTMX page #2* to take me back and reload site *FOO* or site *BAR*, depending on where I started, since both sites include these same elements.  I could add a ? variable in the URL and take it through two levels but I was wondering if there was an easier way.

thanks!